# White screen during registration with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

After sending the form in /register, I get a white screen in the same page.

I don't know how to debug this, any help is appreciated.

Here's the prod.log file (I configured its action_level to 'debug'):

```
[2012-08-14 05:32:20] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_registration_register" (parameters: "_controller": "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction", "path": "/register/", "permanent": "true", "scheme": "null", "httpPort": "80", "httpsPort": "443", "_route": "fos_user_registration_register") [] []
[2012-08-14 05:32:20] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2012-08-14 05:32:20] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2012-08-14 05:32:20] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_registration_register" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction", "_route": "fos_user_registration_register") [] []
[2012-08-14 05:32:20] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2012-08-14 05:32:20] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2012-08-14 05:32:38] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_registration_register" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction", "_route": "fos_user_registration_register") [] []
[2012-08-14 05:32:38] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are some errors that won't be logged by Nginx, PHP, nor Symfony2, when in production mode.

My solution was to clone the site and change this to true in `app.php`:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

So now I have two 'production' instances, one with true and the other with false.

The error was this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in /some/doctrine/file
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a PHP error somewhere. Please look in your Apache error_log file (most of the time it's located in `/var/log/apache`).

In case you don't have Apache, change the following PHP settings in your php.ini:

```
display_errors Off
log_errors On
error_log=/var/log/php_errors.log
```

Comment: I'm not using apache, I'm using nginx. And there are no errors in nginx.error.log

Answer (score 0):

Check apache error log in var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: I'm not using apache, I'm using nginx. And there are no errors in nginx.error.log

Answer (score 0):

You should read http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

i am sure that You forgot to add DoctrineMongoDBBundle to Your bundles in app/AppKernel.php

```
// app/AppKernel.php
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle(),
    );

    // ...
}
```

also check for appropriate files in your vendor dir